# How to change the css of the following line?

Tags: php, css

There is a $message variable. In this variable there is string concatenation happening. I want to use CSS over this variable anyhow and I know this is possible. But I tried so much inline CSS but no result. Please help in this matter.Thanks...

```
$message  = __( 'Someone requested that the password be reset for the following account:' ) . "\r\n\r\n";   
$message .= network_home_url('/') . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login). "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= __('If this was a mistake, just ignore this email and nothing will happen.') . "\r\n\r\n";  $message .= __('To reset your password, visit the following address:') . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= '<' . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login="
  .rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') . ">\r\n";
```

Comment: Don't use inline css. Assign a class and define that class in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can put that inside an HTML tag and provide a style or a class attribute will do just that

```
$message = '<div class="theMessage" style="font-family:Helvetica;color:RED;">Something goes here</div>';
```

and don't forget to close the single and double qoutes. But my guess is, your question is not of PHP, rather it's a Wordpress issue.

Comment: not working using class also.Even text "<div class='xyz'>Someone...</div>" is printed out.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to send an email in php or other technology you have to define your content type html. As in php we use below code for sending an Html message.

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

You can get idea from below link

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php